# Pandas - merge two DataFrames with Identical Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe

I have two Data Frames with identical column names and identical IDs in the first column. With the exception of the ID column, every cell that contains a value in one DataFrame contains NaN in the other. 
Here's an example of what they look like:

```
ID    Cat1    Cat2    Cat3
1     NaN     75      NaN
2     61      NaN     84
3     NaN     NaN     NaN


ID    Cat1    Cat2    Cat3
1     54      NaN     44
2     NaN     38     NaN
3     49      50      53
```

I want to merge them into one DataFrame while keeping the same Column Names. So the result would look like this:

```
ID    Cat1    Cat2    Cat3
1     54      75      44
2     61      38      84
3     49      50      53
```

I tried:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='outer')
```

Which gave me a DataFrame containing twice as many columns. How can I merge the values from each DataFrame into one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want **df.update**. See the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html).

```
df1.update(df2, raise_conflict=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

In this case, the **combine_first** function is appropriate. (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/merging.html)

As the name implies, combine_first takes the first DataFrame and adds to it with values from the second wherever it finds a NaN value in the first.

So:

```
df3 = df1.combine_first(df2)
```

produces a new DataFrame, df3, that is essentially just df1 with values from df2 filled in whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just change the NaN values in df1 with non-NaN values in df2.

```
df1[pd.isnull(df1)] = df2[~pd.isnull(df2)]
```